# Exception while initializing webservice using jax-ws

Tags: java, wsdl, jax-ws, netbeans-6.9

can any one please tell me what the problem is i am trying to create a new web service client in my client side project which already has a web service client i cant seem to figure out what is wrong

Exceptions details : null
java.lang.NullPointerException at java.io.File.(File.java:222) at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.initializePort(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:505) at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.doGet(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:165) at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.invoke(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:100) at org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSServlet.doGet(JAXWSServlet.java:195) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641) at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97) at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165) at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791) at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693) at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954) at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170) at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135) at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102) at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88) at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76) at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53) at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57) at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69) at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330) at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Comment: the error says that it might be because of the same class names but i changed the class names in both services

Comment: this above error come when i test the webservice

Answer (score 0):

This looks like issue [GLASSFISH-14391](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-14391). If not, try searching [JIRA](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH_CORE) with your Glassfish version number and problem details.

Comment: Dead link. I am not able to find the new location. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, when I tried to test the web service not from localhost (`localhost:8080/WebService?Tester`) but from **IP-address** (`192.168.10.11:8080/WebService?Tester` for example). Browser yielded the exception above while GlassFish 3 console wrote something like this:

```
INFO: [ERROR] Server returned HTTP response code: 407 for URL: h ttp://xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx:8080/WebService?WSDL
```

Failed to read the WSDL document: `http://xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx:8080/WebService?WSDL`, because

> 1.could not find the document.
>
> 2.the document could not be read.
>
> 3.the root element of the document is not .

```
INFO: [ERROR] failed.noservice=Could not find wsdl:service in the provided WSDL(s): 
 At least one WSDL with at least one service definition needs to be provided.<br>
INFO:         Failed to parse the WSDL.
INFO: Invoking wsimport with h ttp://xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx:8080/WebService?WSDL<br>
SEVERE: wsimport failed
```

I use a proxy-server for Internet access, so I thought it might be the reason.

Then I went to the GlassFish 3 server properties in IDE (NetBeans, in my case) and switched off the option "*Use IDE proxy settings*". The problem was solved by then.

Hope it can help.